# Reading csv file returns wrong data after updating csv file content

Tags: php, file, csv

I have a csv file named `data1.csv`. The first time i use php to read the csv file content I can get the contents correctly. The problem is I cannot read the new data after I update the data in `data1.csv`. It keeps returning the previous data. What could be the wrong?

```
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    if(!$file_handle) die("Can't open file");

    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
      $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 0, $csv_spliter);

    }

    clearstatcache();

    fclose($file_handle);
    $file_content = $line_of_text;
```

Comment: Is the code from the read that works? Could you show the one that is not working and how you update the csv file?

Comment: This code can read the csv content. The csv is updated manually

Comment: Do you also get the old data if you completely delete the file? If it only affects new lines it could be a line ending problem.

Comment: Does it work if you upload the new file as ``data2.csv`` and change your script to read that new file? If so, then it sure seems like the first file is being cached somewhere. If not, then it would not appear to be a caching problem.

Comment: @RolandStarke I only get the old data, if i change the word `product` to `PRODUCT1`, on csv reading it will show `product`. Note:  I am not adding any new columns/rows just updating already existing data

Comment: did you check is data saved properly or not?

Comment: @kmoser if I change to data2.csv it works fine, i.e it shows the newly updated data

Comment: What is the value of ``$csvFile``?

Comment: @kmoser its a link to the `data1.csv`

Comment: @ovicko Please tell me the exact value. Depending on whether it's a path to a local file, or begins with ``http://`` may affect this.

Comment: @kmoser  `$csvFile = 'https://example.com/feed/data1.csv'`

Comment: @ovicko That's your problem right there. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511476/does-phps-fopen-function-implement-some-kind-of-cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are retrieving data via http/https, it is most likely being cached. See [Does PHPs fopen function implement some kind of cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511476/does-phps-fopen-function-implement-some-kind-of-cache)

Comment: I have tried using solutions stated  still no difference

Comment: Did you try adding a unique query string to the URL every time you attempted to fetch it, e.g. ``https://example.com/feed/data1.csv?12345``?

Comment: @ovicko If my answer works for you, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, thanks!